# Cannot read property 'encrypt' of undefined

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

When I use crypto-js to encrypt text, it throws an error `Cannot read property 'encrypt' of undefined`. What's wrong with my code?

```
...
const Cookies = require('js-cookie');
const request = require('browser-request');
const CryptoJS = require('crypto');

class OssHelper extends Helper {
    addFetchEvent (urlFunction) {
        const createTime = new Date().getTime();
        const encryptUuid = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(Cookies.get('CLIPUUID'), createTime);
    };
}
...
```

Comment: try `var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");` instead of your require, as it says in their docs: https://github.com/brix/crypto-js

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that "AES" is undefined.
Please check how you should use CryptoJS. It seems you did not instanciate an AES object. Shouldn't you require(crypto/aes) and assign it to an AES constant?

```
const AES = require('crypto-js/aes');
...
const encryptUuid = AES.encrypt
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js

Comment: this is for modular load.  require as such `var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");` should give him access to all methods per written in docs. and also in this method require should be `const AES = require('crypto-js/aes');`

Comment: @FedeSc - sure, but require does not guarantee that members are initialized, am I wrong? But you were right, missed the '-js' in sample above. Corrected.

Are we sure we are talking about same library as Hydrostatic? Which crypto library does Hydrostatic want to use?

Answer (score 0):

you are installing crypto-js with command (if you are using npm of course) npm install crypto-js, not crypto, (crypto is other built in module of nodeJS), so you got to require crypto-js not crypto with code: `var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js')`

Comment: But when I import crypto like this, it throws `Can't find module` error

Comment: check package json is there crypto-js module?

Comment: But it is in the "devDependencies" of package.json. @Jake

Comment: try: `npm uninstall crypto-js` and then `npm install crypto-js`

Comment: OK. I'll try it.